# Part of string comparison always inexplicably returns False

Tags: python

I have a simple Python script and I do not understand why I always get `False` as a return of that string comparison. What's wrong here?

```
inputStr = "upload test"
print(inputStr[:7] == "upload") # -> False
```

In return the next code returns `True`:

```
inputStr = "upload"
print(inputStr[:7] == "upload") # -> True
```

On the other hand when I use the keyword `in`, it works just fine (it prints out `True`):

```
inputStr = "upload test"
print("upload" in inputStr[:7]) # -> True
```

Can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the results of this code `inputStr[:7]` in fist block is:

> 'upload '

and `'upload '` is not equal to `'upload'`

because it counts from index 0 to 6

and the reason you get true in this input: `inputStr = "upload"`
is that there are only 6 characters in the string

so if you want fist block to return true
you should use this block of code:

```
inputStr = "upload test"
print(inputStr[:6] == "upload")
```

Comment: Oh yeah, true! Thanks for your help! What a stupid mistake! I've never understood, why it didn't work, because in the console you can not see the spaces at the end of course.

Answer (score 1):

`inputStr[:7]` returns `'upload '` and not `'upload'`.

As well as that, I would suggest you use `str.startswith()` instead of slicing!

example:

```py
print(inputStr.startswith("upload")) # -> True
```

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

```
inputStr = "upload test"
print(inputStr[:7] == "upload")
```

it takes characters from 0 to 6 ("upload " with space) which is not equal to "upload". so change `inputStr[:7]` to `inputStr[:6]`.

Case 2: returns True because in the input string there there is only "upload" so `inputStr[:7]` still gives "upload" which is equal to "upload".

Case 3: the 'in' keyword returns true because "upload" is in "upload "(inputStr[:7]).

Answer (score 0):

Python indexing is 0 based. inputstr[::7] returns "upload " (with a space at the end) not "upload".
whereas inputstr[::7] in the 2nd case returns "upload" because 7 is outside the length scope of the string.

To answer your question, the statement needs to be `print(inputStr[:6] == "upload")`